# proof of continuous function for any real x

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have a function :

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{sin(nx)}{n^2} \cdot x^2
$$

How is this function a continuous function for any $x \in \mathbb R $?
I cannot prove it..

Comment: Hint: The series converges uniformly on any finite interval.

Comment: Yes. You're right! It is a infinity sum! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, we show that the function $g\colon x\mapsto \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx) }{n^2}$ is continuous. To this aim, fix $x_0\in\mathbf R$, $\varepsilon\gt 0$, and note that for a fixed $N$,
$$|g(x)-g(x_0)| \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{| \sin(nx)-\sin(nx_0)|}{n^2} +\sum_{n\geqslant N}   \frac 1{n(n-1)}\\
\leqslant \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{|x-x_0|}{n} +\frac 1{N-1}   .$$
Choose $N$ such that  $ 1/(N-1)\leqslant \varepsilon$ to deduce the continuity at $x_0$.